# SFMC - Transactional Messaging API - Subscriber status

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, subscriber

We would like to send an order confirmation to anyone who makes a purchase. Even if that user does not have an active status because of a bounce in an earlier mail.

Does the Transactional Messaging API take this status into account? Or is the mail always sent regardless of the status? 
I can't find this anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to send a real time email via Triggered sends SFMC, then you have an option to un-check 'Add subscribers to this list'. If you do so then SFMC won't look for the existing account details.

But note that SFMC has its own email validation for example lets say if the email address is '123@gn' then it won't try to send an email.

[image]

Comment: So if I uncheck this checkbox. The email will be send even if the status of the subscriber in 'All subscribers' is set to 'Held', 'Bounced' or 'Unsubscribed'?

Comment: @user6079228 thats right. But note the above point which i mentioned. We can't restrict those scenarios of invalid email address based on SFMC